# Is ASEA supplement useful against scars or it is a fake product?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, supplement

3 months ago I obtained normotrophic scar on my face in place of eyelid. All this time I was looking for remedies to minimize scarring and somehow improve appearance of scar. I was advised to use different things: silicone gels, silicone patches, creams, Vitamin E, massaging and so on.

One physician recommended me to use ASEA supplement.
It is described as:

> ​ASEA is the world’s first and only bio-active solution to fortify the immune and healing system through Redox Signaling. ASEA is the only product in the world that provides native, stabilized Redox Signaling molecules to the body’s cells.
>
> ​​ASEA is a natural supplement that repairs, replaces and revitalizes
>   every cell—telomeres in the the body. ASEA harnesses the power of
>   Redox Signaling to fortify the immune and healing system at a most
>   basic level. Redox Signaling molecules are the body’s answer to
>   cellular efficiency and communication.
>
> Cells that work at optimum levels and communicate freely and quickly
>   with each other facilitate the immune and healing system’s function to
>   repair, replace and revitalize every cell – allowing it to operate at
>   its best and empowering the body to heal itself.

For now, I am very skeptical about this product. Actually, it looks like some fake product designed just to make money.

I've checked the product on Amazon and I noticed that there are a lot of positive reviews on this product from real people.

Creators of the product claim to have a science behind this product.

---

How do you think is ASEA supplement really useful and can help people minimize scars or it is just one of the snake oil type products?

Comment: Plz. You are not talking about that product that has the following review at the very top of the list?: "The ingredients say sodium and chloride?? Is that it?? snake oil anyone??
Answer: That's what it says alright. It's nothing by salt water. Waste of money. Did nothing for me and I quit using it." The language used by the company should usually be enough to convince most sensible people to never buy anything from amazon again, since they tolerate and profit from these ripoffs as well.

Comment: Save yourself some money. Fill an 8-oz glass with tap water. Stir in about 6 teaspoons of table salt. Ta da! You just made ASEA. Oh, and that "physician" who recommended it? Find a new one.

Answer (score 4):

I was quite skeptical to read the word describing the product in the questions title.

But there is really no weaker word allowed to describe this extraordinary scam.

Their website is full of it but does not list anything remotely coming close to a list of ingredients.

They have a sub-page called "science-faq". That lists probably the loophole their legal team dug out for them:

> <sub>Redox signaling technology has not been evaluated by the FDA. However, ASEA manufacturing is FDA registered, NSF certified, and meets all FDA Good Manufacturing Practices (GMP). NSF International’s GMP Registration Program enables manufacturers to become independently registered by NSF to meet GMP requirements. The program is open to manufacturers of dietary supplements who want to demonstrate their commitment to public safety. These GMP requirements are listed in Section 8 of NSF/ANSI 173, which is the only accredited American National Standard in the dietary supplement industry developed in accordance with the FDA’s 21 CFR part 111.</sub>

Health claims on the order delivered here are not evaluated, independent testing nowhere to be found.

To get closer to the truth, we have to read the label on the bottle:

[image: Nutritional Info]

And yeah. Sodium and Chloride *are* vital elements, they play a role in diverse "signalling processes"? So what now?

Their claims have to be taken with a pinch of salt. Conveniently their product delivers just that. **And nothing more, dissolved in water**.

Looks like everyone should buy one bottle, just to participate in a following lawsuit against the manufacturer, the marketers and every seller and market place involved in this. If indeed a real physician recommended this he should be reported to some authorities that might take some action on this multi-level marketing frauds and this accomplice.

---

Although one picture says more than the words needed to deride this pile of money well invested, here is nice write up:

> [**ASEA: Another Expensive Way to Buy Water:**](https://sciencebasedmedicine.org/asea-another-expensive-way-to-buy-water/)
>
> > ASEA is made in Utah from municipal water that is highly purified using both reverse osmosis and distillation. The pure water is then combined with pure salt and allowed to cure, before undergoing a patented process that oxidizes and reduces the saline solution into the final product. During processing most of the chloride ions are integrated into redox molecules. Sodium ions are not effected [sic] and help to maintain electrical neutrality. Hydrogen and oxygen also contribute to the formation of redox molecules, but most of the water forms a matrix of clusters around the active redox molecules and ions. This micro-clustering further contributes to the stability and electrical neutrality of the product. The final product is no longer a saline solution. It is not salt and water. It is a balanced buffet of redox molecules. The raw materials have been transformed into a new product. Ingredients: Some people ask why redox Molecules are not listed as an ingredient on each bottle of ASEA. By comparison, when we look at the ingredients on a loaf of bread, we find flour, water, eggs, sugar, oil, yeast, etc. Nowhere on the list does it say “bread”. The raw ingredients have been blended and heated and forever transformed. You can no longer locate the eggs or oil that we know went into the process. It’s the same with ASEA.
>
> This is very creative, but it’s not science. It’s just an attempt to baffle you with bull****.